# Residue evaluation question

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure as to how this equation was evaluated to be $1/6$. Is it simply algebra with $\left(z-1/\sqrt2\right) f(z)$ ? I think I'm missing something with the limit as $z$ approaches $1/\sqrt2$ but I'm not good with limits and am unsure how the limit affects the equation (what to do with the limit?) so how would I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what is the definition of residue? You'll need to factor the denominator to find poles.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as from my notes, I haven't been able to understand much. My understanding of a residue is that it's the coefficient of the -1 term of a Laurent series. I have found the singularities which are simple poles at +- sqrt(2) and +- 1/sqrt(2). May I ask how this helps in evaluating the 1/6?

Comment: Since there is a simple pole at $z= {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$, the residue $a_{-1}$ is straighforward to evaluate.

Comment: Assuming that the $f$ is correct above, both residues should be $-{1 \over 6}$. What text is this from?

Comment: Write out the expression of $f$ in terms of simple poles, multiply by the factor as you have in the question (which will eliminate one term on the denominator) and then compute the limit.

Comment: Ah thank you! I managed to reach an answer of -1/6 as well. I think my issue was just simply an algebra issue as originally when I kept expanding the factor and $f$, I kept getting a 0 in the denominator somehow. Thank you very much!